# Как создать пользовательский компонент в 1с-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день.
Самостоятельно изучаю битрикс и возник вопрос, а как создавать собственные компоненты типа  bitrix:news или bitrix:catalog? В админке не нахожу такой функции. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если вы говорите об модификации компонента, то тогда через [эрмитаж](http://joxi.ru/E2ppMXLcBYxMQ2).

Если вы говорите об создании собственного компонента, то тогда вам нужно смотреть уроки от [битрикса](https://academy.1c-bitrix.ru/education/index.php?COURSE_ID=66&LESSON_ID=5888&LESSON_PATH=5863.5888) на эту тему.